# Can't change permissions on USB or System Hard Drives in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I know there has been a lot of threads about this issue and most have been cleared up but not mine.  I am a newbie and the terminal commands must be over my head.  I tried to use pysdm but when it loads, it shows the drives on left window but everything on the right side is faded grey and no changes can be made.  I had loaded pysdm via the software manager and then uninstalled and did the install via the terminal but same results.

So can someone walk a dummy like me through how to fix the permission issues on external USB drives, Internal Mounted Hard Drives and then on how to get Pysdm to work correctly?

Comment: Run it with superuser permissions?

Answer (score 1):

didn't it asks for password? Open terminal and run `gksu pysdm`.

A detailed guide is here → http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=872197